# Concatenating multiple csv files into one dataframe gives me additional column

Tags: python, pandas

My CSV has only two columns like:

[image]

I have multiple CSVs that have this format and tried to concatenate all of them using this:

```
path = r'...'
all_files = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')

df_from_each_file = [pd.read_csv(f, error_bad_lines=False) for f in all_files]
concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

However, this gives me

```
    a   a.1 a.2 command      description
0   NaN NaN NaN aaa ikegroup WORD   Name of the IKE group
1   NaN NaN NaN aaa ikegroup <cr>   NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN aaa locald trace    Show trace data for the locald component(cisco...
3   NaN NaN NaN aaa login trace Show trace data for login sub system
4   NaN NaN NaN aaa password-policy statistics  Show statistics related to password policy
```

and I don't know where the first three columns came from.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True, axis=1)`

Comment: Actually, that just gives me the same output

Comment: Have you gone through `df_from_each_file` to confirm that all dataframes are what's expected

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am seeing `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: And yeah, each dataframe looks like what I am expecting

Comment: What is the value of `all_files`? Is it possible you globbed a bad file?

Comment: I think the name of the columns is a clue. `a`, `a.1`, `a.2` is not random. It is taking the `aaa` from your `command` text. Please share the values of all CSV files that you are globbing so we can see if you have a malformed CSV, missing header, or other

Comment: I think pandas get confused infering the columns at some files. Maybe there are some files without column names in the first row. Try explicitely specifying the separator (assuming that it is the same in all files): `pd.read_csv(f, error_bad_lines=False, skiprows=1, names=['command','description'], sep='\s+')`

Comment: Can you please share the raw csv file ?